# Do access modifiers matter for the method Main?

Tags: c#

Do the available access modifiers matter for the method Main? If not, why does Main allow us to specify the modifier? Why does the compiler not prevent us from specifying something that are trivial?

Comment: `Main must be static and it should not be public.` - source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx

Comment: Find John Steeks answer for related question


http://stackoverflow.com/a/3736037/823369

Comment: The static modifier means that it does not have to be instantiated to use it. Before a program runs there are technically no objects created yet, so the main method, which is the entry point for the application must be labeled static to tell the compiler that the method can be used without having first to create an instance of that class. Otherwise, it is the "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?" phenomenon.

Comment: Asked differently, why would they stop you from using access modifiers on the entrypoint if they don't really matter anyway? But it does matter - you could also call it as a normal method (that's a big WTF IMO but you *can*). Also the entrypoint does not have to be called Main.

Comment: @harold you can edit my question to accomodate your question that i wanted to say actually. i am not  native   so my english expression is limited.

Comment: Your question and your English seem fine to me.

Comment: @JohnWoo Maybe, if the class (or struct) in which the Main method resides, also contains static fields with field initializers and/or a static constructor, can you be completely sure no other code (which might create objects) will run before your `Main` method? I think not.

Comment: @Oded actually, your quote is wrong ATM. Your link currently shows this phrase: `Main must be static and it need not be public.` there's a *big* difference between "should not" and "need not", both in CS docs and in common English.

Comment: @vax guess that has changed in the 5 years since I wrote that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Main being public/private does not affect the CLR calling it at all.
The CLR will look for a static method named main (by default, but not necessarily) which is associated with its entry point, **without looking at access modifiers**.

It only affects the visibility of main to the other functions.
Good practice is for Main to **not be public** since it is not to be called by other methods in your assemblies, only by the CLR.